# Photoshop Action to make mirrored tiling images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, transform, actions, tiles

Let's say I have many 1:1 ratio (square) images of varying pixel dimensions and I want to make them double the resolution and flip them on both X and Y axes so that they create a mirrored tile.

For example, going from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

It's easy to do manually, but how can I program it as an Action?

All the operations for moving the duplicated and flipped layers that I can think of are specified in pixel dimensions, not percentages. This has so far prevented me from being able to define an Action that works for images of all sizes.

<sub>Image courtesy of [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/photos/landscape-bike-cycling-china-sport-3941630/)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I got it.

The trick was to use the Transform tool instead of dragging manually or using Offset.

### Steps in the Action

<sub>Note: Assumes we are starting with a flat image.</sub>

**1. Set Background** Double-click on the layer titled *Background* so that it becomes *Layer 0*.

**2. Canvas Size** Set Width and Height to 100%, Relative, with the Anchor in one of the corners.

[image]

**3. Duplicate Current Layer** Drag the layer to the [+] in the Layers Panel

**4. Transform Current Layer** <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> Place the anchor opposite of where it was during the Canvas Size operation. Set Width to -100%.

[image]

**5. Merge Layers** <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>

**6. Duplicate Current Layer** Drag the layer to the [+] in the Layers Panel

**7. Transform Current Layer** <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> Place the anchor on the top or bottom, whichever is the center of the image for you. Set Height to -100%.

[image]

**8. Flatten Image** Layer → Flatten Image

<sub>The Action can of course be defined in four different ways, depending on which corner you use as your Anchor.</sub>